# Strategy to auto-generate PHP code?

Tags: php

I'm developing a framework which programs parts of itself dynamically after creating ER-Diagrams in the backend. As a PHP newbie I wonder if there's anything much fancier than just opening a plain xyz.php text file and then adding the dynamically generated code to that file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, try out [Zend_CodeGenerator](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.codegenerator.html)

Answer (score 2):

Or [ezcPhpGenerator](http://www.ezcomponents.org/docs/tutorials/PhpGenerator)